# Heatmap series name doesnt show up

Tags: highcharts

Following the demo example for the heatmap chart,

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/heatmap/)

the series name doesnt show up for me, what am i missing?

```
series: [{
    name: 'Sales per employee',
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: [[0, 0, 10], [0, 1, 19], [0, 2, 8], [0, 3, 24], [0, 4, 67], [1, 0, 92], [1, 1, 58], [1, 2, 78], [1, 3, 117], [1, 4, 48], [2, 0, 35], [2, 1, 15], [2, 2, 123], [2, 3, 64], [2, 4, 52], [3, 0, 72], [3, 1, 132], [3, 2, 114], [3, 3, 19], [3, 4, 16], [4, 0, 38], [4, 1, 5], [4, 2, 8], [4, 3, 117], [4, 4, 115], [5, 0, 88], [5, 1, 32], [5, 2, 12], [5, 3, 6], [5, 4, 120], [6, 0, 13], [6, 1, 44], [6, 2, 88], [6, 3, 98], [6, 4, 96], [7, 0, 31], [7, 1, 1], [7, 2, 82], [7, 3, 32], [7, 4, 30], [8, 0, 85], [8, 1, 97], [8, 2, 123], [8, 3, 64], [8, 4, 84], [9, 0, 47], [9, 1, 114], [9, 2, 31], [9, 3, 48], [9, 4, 91]],
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: '#000000'
    }
}]
```

Comment: Please try to ask your question more precisely. Where exactly do you want to show the series name, in legend element?

Comment: @daniel_s this is the demo provided from highcharts (the code is not modified at all), i dont know where it should be displayed all i can see is that it doesnt show up anywhere on the chart... but if you ask me where i want to be display i would like to be below the X axis

Answer (score 0):

After consulting the topic in comments below the question, you can set your series name as `Axis.title` inside of `Chart.events.load` event function, using `setTitle()` method. Then it should be dynamically set at every chart load basing on your current series name. Here is the code which shows how to achieve it:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load() {
      var chart = this
      var seriesName = chart.series[0].name

      chart.xAxis[0].setTitle({ text: seriesName, style: { fontWeight: 'bold' } })
    }
  }
}
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/9rcsqyov/

API Reference:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setTitle

Comment: i know that i can add Axis title like this yAxis: {
        categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
        title: {
          text: 'Sales per employee'
        }       
    },
but if i go with this, if the title is too long it will be cut off

Comment: The reason why too long text will be cut is rigidly set margin. After we remove these lines, text will not be cut off: marginTop: 40, marginBottom: 80

Comment: Please, don't forget about marking the answer if it helps you.